# Repaired GRUB, now how can I boot into other OSs?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have done a repair on GRUB. I have installed Windows xp and Windows 7 along with Ubuntu. Now I am not getting the other OSs in my GRUB menu after the repair.

Comment: When you can boot into Ubuntu, you can run the following command line from a terminal window, `sudo update-grub` and it should find the other operating systems and create grub menu entries. After the next reboot you should be able to select the other operating systems.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the timely advice.  That was fast and solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you can boot into Ubuntu, you can run the following command line from a terminal window,

```
sudo update-grub
```

and it should find the other operating systems and create grub menu entries. After the next reboot you should be able to select the other operating systems.

See the following link for more details,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup)

Scroll down and you will find details about `update-grub` and further down details about `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`, which is called from `update-grub`. This script uses `os-prober` to search for Linux and other operating systems and places the results in the GRUB 2 menu.